# Android: pause Widget updates using Alarmmanager

Tags: android, android-widget, alarmmanager

I just went through this tutorial:
[update-widget-in-onreceive-method](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/update-widget-in-onreceive-method.html)
(btw: would you propose any improvements to that code?)

At the end someone mentions:

> I'm just wondering if there is a way to extend this further so that when the device is asleep (screen off), the updates stop. Then when the device wakes up, the updates resume.

So my question: is there a way of doing this? how?
or is the alarmmanager automatically stopped? - I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify whether the device will wake up when scheduling the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

*Quote from the documentation:*

> ELAPSED_REALTIME
>   Alarm time in SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() (time
>   since boot, including sleep). **This alarm does not wake the device up**; if it goes off while the device is asleep, it will not be delivered until the next time the device wakes up.
>
> ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP
>   Alarm time in
>   SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() (time since boot, including sleep),
>   **which will wake up the device when it goes off**.

Same goes for `AlarmManager.RTC` and `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP`

So you probably want one of the two `AlarmManager.RTC` or `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME`. These continue while the device is awake and stop when the device is in standby. If this alarm is triggered while the device is asleep it will be delivered when the user turns the device back on though, exactly what you want. And no, the AlarmManagers scheduled alarms are not cancelled automatically in general.

The part mentioned here can be found in [this part of the tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/app-widget-using-alarm-manager.html), specific this line:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 20*1000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: This is slightly misleading. Even if you use ELAPSED_REALTIME, the alarm may fire when the screen is asleep, as explained in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/Airlo3g5luw).